# How to undo an 'svn copy'

Tags: svn, copy, undo

I've accidentally overwritten an old branch by copying trunk over it using 'svn copy'. More specifically, for every release, trunk is branched and kept as a tag, using:

```
svn copy svn://machine/REPOS/trunk svn://machine/REPOS/tags/$RELEASENR
```

But this time the value of 'RELEASENR' was that of an old existing branch instead of a new one. Anybody have any ideas on how to undo this mistake? Thanks already!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Subversion doesn't work that way.  You haven't actually overwritten it. If the target of the copy or a move exists and is a directory, then the copied or moved item is placed *in* that directory:

```
svn copy svn://machine/REPOS/trunk svn://machine/REPOS/tags/EXISTS_ALREADY
```

If you look, you should find:

```
svn://machine/REPOS/tags/EXISTS_ALREADY/trunk
```

Which is a copy of the trunk you just tried to tag.  The fix in this case is easy:

```
svn mv svn://machine/REPOS/tags/EXISTS_ALREADY/trunk \
       svn://machine/REPOS/tags/CORRECT_TAG_NAME
```

(In case you're not *nix conversant: The \ means I've broken one logical line into two physical lines to spare your horizontal scrollbar from overwork.)

Comment: I suspect that if his procedure is identical for all releases, he has actually overwritten the existing trunk in EXIST_ALREADY directory.

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful. However, I chose to undo the cp and re-create the tag, because the commit message was also incorrect (it contained the name of the existing tag instead of the name of the new tag) and because I like to keep the change histories uniform and simple for all tags. To undo the cp: `svn co svn://machine/REPOS/tags/EXISTS_ALREADY/ EXISTS_ALREADY`, `cd EXISTS_ALREADY`, `svn merge -c -REVISION_OF_INCORRECT_CP .`, `svn commit`.

Answer (score 5):

In order to undo

```
svn cp OLDFOLDER NEWFOLDER
```

if the change has not yet been committed, just use

```
svn revert NEWFOLDER --depth=infinity
```

Answer (score 2):

You can undo your last revision by merging back to the previous revision. 
See http://anilsaldhana.blogspot.com/2007/11/svn-undo-change.html

```
svn merge --revision 92:91 .
```

and then commit